# Price set for Golf Event

Tags: civievent

Needing to have a single golfer price of $100
OR
Foursome at $80 each and collect data on each person.
I can turn on Addtl Participants
BUT
How do a "make" them enter four people and not more or less when choosing Foursome.
I'm guessing this would have to be a custom built page?
THANKS for any input.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Drupal, I would guess you can do this with [Webform-CiviCRM](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm). For example, you might be able to use Webform Conditionals (which comes built in with [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform)) so that if they select the "Single golfer" option on the payment amount it hides the other three contacts, and if they select "Foursome" it shows the additional contacts (and those fields can be marked required in the Webform Components section).

Comment: I forgot to put we are using WordPress.

Comment: Then I'd guess you need a custom built page of some kind. I don't think you can do this out of the box.